# Erastotenes Sieve in paraller programm Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to make a programm which count prime numbers using Erastotenes Sieve. In this issue I want to use semaphore to communicate between thread to make calculations on table with numbers.
So far I have written code like that.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Podaj gorny zakres\n");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Erastotenes erastotenes = new Erastotenes(Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()));
        erastotenes.initializeTable();


        long start = System.nanoTime();

        List<SingleProcess.MyThread> list = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> numbers = Dollar.$(2,erastotenes.getMaximumNumber()+1).toList();

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            list.add(new SingleProcess.MyThread(erastotenes,numbers.subList((numbers.size()/2)*i,(numbers.size()/2)*i+numbers.size()/2)));
            list.get(list.size()-1).start();
            list.get(list.size()-1).join();
        }

        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - start);

        //System.out.println("Liczba elementów: "+erastotenes.countPrimeElements());
    }
```

Erastotenes class.

```
public class Erastotenes {

    private int upperRange;
    private int maximumNumber;
    private int table[];

    public Erastotenes(int upperRange) {
        this.upperRange = upperRange;
        this.maximumNumber = (int)(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(upperRange)));
        this.table = new int[upperRange+1];
    }


    public int getMaximumNumber() {
        return maximumNumber;
    }

    public int getUpperRange() {
        return upperRange;
    }

    public void initializeTable()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=upperRange;i++) {
            table[i] = i;
        }

    }

    public void makeSelectionOfGivenNumber(int number)
    {
        if (table[number] != 0) {
            int multiple;
            multiple = number+number;
            while (multiple<=upperRange) {
                table[multiple] = 0;
                multiple += number;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getList()
    {
        List<Integer> list = Ints.asList(table);
        return  list.stream().filter(item->item.intValue()!=0 && item.intValue()!=1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The class describing single Thread to make calculations with static Semaphore looks like this.

```
public class SingleProcess {

    static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    static class MyThread extends Thread {

        Erastotenes erastotenes;
        List<Integer> numbers;

        MyThread(Erastotenes erastotenes,List<Integer> numbers) {
            this.erastotenes = erastotenes;
            this.numbers=numbers;
        }


        public void run() {
            for(int number:numbers) {
                try {
                    semaphore.acquire();
                    //1System.out.println(number + " : got the permit!");
                    erastotenes.makeSelectionOfGivenNumber(number);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    semaphore.release();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I thought that splitting on half table with numbers from 2 to maximum numbers as square root like in erastotrenes algorithm for these two Threads will boost calculations, but with upperRange to 100000000 the difference between paraller and sequence is not so big. How can I in another realize this problem of paraller programming Erastotenes Sieve?

Comment: What does `Dollar.$(2,erastotenes.getMaximumNumber()+1)` do?

Comment: Fill list from to 2 to number given in scanner. In that way I can split list into two subList each of them into particular Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        list.add(new SingleProcess.MyThread(erastotenes,numbers.subList((numbers.size()/2)*i,(numbers.size()/2)*i+numbers.size()/2)));
        list.get(list.size()-1).start();
        list.get(list.size()-1).join();
    }
```

You start a thread and then immediately wait for it to finish; that kills the parallelism entirely. You can start and wait in the end:

```
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        list.add(new SingleProcess.MyThread(erastotenes,numbers.subList((numbers.size()/2)*i,(numbers.size()/2)*i+numbers.size()/2)));
        list.get(list.size()-1).start();
    }
    for (Thread t : list) {
        t.join();
    }
```

But, there's also a problem with your semaphore tbh. Each thread blocks all other threads from doing anything as long as it's working on a number; that means that again, all parallelism is gone.

You can do away with the semaphore altogether IMO; there's not really a lot of danger in setting the same index to 0 several times, which is all that happens in this "critical section" - but it's not critical at all because no one ever reads the array value in question before all threads are finished.

Comment: Can it be possible with using Semaphore and keep the parallelism?

Comment: @maciejka just remove the semaphore altogether and change the joining as I posted, it will run in parallel.

Comment: it works fine, but still I have a question. In this erastotenes sieve using semaphore is useless to guarantee synchronization and proper working?

Comment: @maciejka Yes. You need synchronization if there is a conflict between concurrent reading and writing. If you are only writing and never reading, there really is not much point to synchronizing.

Comment: @maciejka wait, I'm wrong, you do read the array, when you select the next number to sieve... it's possible for a thread to start sieving a number that doesn't need to be sieved (for example, 100, because the sieve for 2 hasn't gotten around to setting array[100] to 0 yet). That doesn't matter though, it's doing superfluous work, but it still gets the correct result.

Comment: So mayble apply Class where each object has number anf flag boolean flag isChecked and put all elements into array to avoid sieving number 100 like you written in example, the performance woudln't be better?

Comment: @maciejka try it out. I'd guess the effort of managing that takes more time than it saves.

Comment: Yeah, that't rights, but starting each thread from 2 also worse a litte performance. Should it be better to start from another number?

Comment: @maciejka yes, of course, I didn't even notice that; this will just do the same work again and again. You'd have to give each thread a starting and ending number, or something.